# Is there a way to fail an automated test upon Netty leak detection?

Tags: memory-leaks, automated-tests, netty

I'm using Netty 4.0.x on a project where a core separate project will create `ByteBuf` buffers and pass them to the client code layer, which should be responsible for closing the buffer.

I've found leaks in some cases and I'd like to cover the codepath leading to those leaks with an automated test, but Netty's ResourceLeakDetector seems to only report leaks inside logs.

Is there a way to fail an automated JUnit test in the event of such a leak? (eg by plugin some behavior in the ResourceLeakDetector)?

Thanks!

PS: Keep in mind that my test wouldn't really create the buffers, the core code (which is a dependency) does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Netty's CI server leak build](http://clinker.netty.io/jenkins/job/netty-leak/) will indicate that the build is unstable if leaks are detected.  I'm not sure on the mechanism for this but it is possible (possibly detecting the leak messages from build logs) to automatically detect.

Keep in mind that the leaks are detected when the ByteBuf objects are GC. So when/where a leak is detected may be far removed from when/where the leak actually occurred.  Netty does include a trail of places where the ByteBuf has been accessed in meaningful ways to help you trace back where the buffer was originally allocated, and potentially a list of objects who may be responsible for releasing that buffer.

If you are OK with the above limitations you could add a throw of an exception into [ResourceLeakDetector](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/5725e804bcfbd0c76e0f11e7911a76970eb06c8c/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/ResourceLeakDetector.java#L209) for private use.